# What files do I need for slipstreaming drivers?

Tags: images, drivers, unattended

I am under the impression that if I use 7zip or similar to extract driver files, I only need to keep the `.inf` files and not the `.cat`, `.dll`, or anything else that may be contained in a folder?

Generally speaking, is this correct?

I am aware that this (if correct) would leave me with just the plain drivers and none of the suites like ATI Catalyst Control Center, and that is actually preferable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the driver type, you will need other files besides the inf. The inf is just an installation script, it is dependent on the actual driver files being present.

They could include but not limited to:

.cat

.sys

.dll

.drv

The inf script will install the proper driver files without additional software.

You can read the inf file with notepad.

.

Comment: Thank you! I had always read that the .inf "provides information about the hardware", I never knew that information was where the necessary files were. :) With that information I have cracked open some inf files and I can see exactly what files need to acompany them. Thanks so much!

Comment: I remember when I first learned about inf hacking, oh what fun...https://encrypted.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=inf+hacking